# Dynamic DropDown List not returning any value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hey guys i need your help, i have a create employee form in MVC. I fill the form and select from the dropdown list and when i click submit, every other field returns a value except for the dropdown. i can't seem to fix the problem. this is what the form looks like.

[image]

this is the CreateEmployee Model

```
    public class CreateEmployee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public int Department { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AngTestDepartment> Departments { get; set; }

    public bool PerkCar { get; set; }
    public bool PerkStock { get; set; }
    public bool PerkSixWeeks { get; set; }
    public string PayrollType { get; set; }
}
```

the action controller

```
public ActionResult Employee(){
using (var db = new DepartmentDbContext())
{
    var model = new CreateEmployee();
    model.Departments = db.AngTestDepartments.ToList();
    return View(model);
} }
```

and the view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEmployee", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
```

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Employee</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    // the drop down  doesnt return a value on submit
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Departments,
                Model.Departments.Select(d => new SelectListItem()
                                                {
                                                    Value = d.id.ToString(),
                                                    Text = d.Department
                                                }
                                    ), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div> }
```

and the action result called on submit

```
        public ActionResult CreateEmployee(CreateEmployee newEmployee)
    {
        DbEmployeeTable.DbEmployeeTable_EmployeeTable(newEmployee);
        return RedirectToAction("Employees");
    }
```

thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the dropdownlist code to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, new SelectList(Model.Departments.Select(d => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = d.id.ToString(),
        Text = d.Department
    }
)), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Dropdownlistfor's first argument should be the value that you're trying to get, and having the second be a select list will save you persistence-related headaches later.

As an aside, I'd also make the Model.Departments.Select result a model property so you don't clutter your view so much, but that's just a style concern.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Departments,
```

try this...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department,
```

That should return the department Id as an int from the selected value.

Comment: f**k yea, mxmissle. thank a lot for the help. problem solved.